# Continue to next stage when partial matrix/parallel is complete

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm working on a Jenkins Pipeline script that needs to run work on 3 servers in parallel but needs to continue to work on 4 different servers when at least one of the servers finishes the work they are performing. I'm unsure if this is possible with Jenkins but if it is it would greatly help with the job I'm currently working on.

I've already tried googling this and looking through documentation for matrix and parallel stages in Jenkins, but I'm either looking for the wrong terms or the information or ability to do this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to implement this in different ways, following one way to do this with [Lockable Resource Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/). The idea is from each initial stages you will call external stage execution and whoever comes first will acquire a lock preventing others from executing.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('1') {
                    steps {
                        echo "Running something here"
                        runOtherStepsOrStages()
                        
                    }
                }
                stage('2') {
                    steps {
                        echo "run-tests.sh"
                        runOtherStepsOrStages()
                    }
                }
                 stage('3') {
                    steps {
                        echo "run-tests.sh"
                        runOtherStepsOrStages()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def runOtherStepsOrStages(){
    // Only one Stage will be able to aquare the lock, once aquiredother will skip, you can add another flag to make sure it's not executed again after the stage is completed
    lock(resource: 'myLock', skipIfLocked: true) {
        echo "Storing the steps/stages externally to reuse."
        sleep 30
    }
}
```